# Angular - detect active route in ngIf

Tags: angular, routes

I want to display a different markup for active and inactive menu items so that active menu item doesn't include `a` tag:

```
<li>
    <a routerLink="/abc">Inactive</a>
</li>    
<li>Active</li>
```

The `routerLinkActive` directive doesn't help here since it can only add some class for active route but not to use a different markup. I understand that I can inject `Router` to my component and use something like this

```
<li>
    <ng-container *ngIf="router.isActive('/abc')">Active</ng-container>
    <a *ngIf="!router.isActive('/abc')" routerLink="/abc">Inactive</a>
</li>
```

but is there a better built-in solution for this case?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to remove the active `<a>` tag? The router won't react to a click on it and if you change the `pointer` via css for the active link, it shouldn't be confusing for the user either. Imo the simplest approach unless you have an important reason to remove the `<a>` completely.

Comment: Mostly markup requirements. Yes, I was also thinking about using css to make it look like non-link element

Answer (score 7):

> The routerLinkActive directive doesn't help here since it can only add some class for active route but not to use a different markup.

Well actually...

```
<input type="hidden" [routerLink]="'home'" routerLinkActive #home="routerLinkActive" />
<section *ngIf="home.isActive"></section>
```

The `routerLinkActive` variable is bound to a template variable and then re-used as required. Unfortunately the only caveat is that you can't have this all on the `<section>` element as `#home` needs to be resolved prior to the parser hitting `<section>`.